Issue on reading the GEFSv12 data with xarray and cfgrib
I'd like to read the GEFSv12 reforecast data (downloaded from AWS Cloud). The dataset contains control run (c00) and perturbed forecast (p01-p04). Things are perfectly fine for c00, but it went wrong for the perturbed forecast.
This is my code:
import numpy as np 
import xarray as xr  
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta  
import glob


lats,latn = -20, 20
lon1, lon2 = 60,180
var = 'tp'
ens = ['c00','p01','p02','p03','p04']

for n in [1]: # to read every member, do range(0,5)
    ds = (xr.open_mfdataset('/data_path/'+ens[n]+'/d01-10/apcp_sfc_*.grib2',
                            combine = "nested",
                            concat_dim='time',
                            engine='cfgrib',
                            parallel=True)
            .sortby('time'))

I got error:

DatasetBuildError: multiple values for unique key, try re-open the file with one of:
filter_by_keys={'dataType': 'cf'}
filter_by_keys={'dataType': 'pf'}

So I tried to add the filter_by_keys,
    cf = (xr.open_mfdataset('/data_path/'+ens[n]+'/d01-10/apcp_sfc_*.grib2',
                            combine = "nested",
                            concat_dim='time',
                            engine='cfgrib',
                            parallel=True,
                            filter_by_keys={'dataType': 'cf'})
            .sortby('time'))
    pf = (xr.open_mfdataset('/data_path/'+ens[n]+'/d01-10/apcp_sfc_*.grib2',
                            combine = "nested",
                            concat_dim='time',
                            engine='cfgrib',
                            parallel=True,
                            filter_by_keys={'dataType': 'pf'})
            .sortby('time'))

The preview of cf and pf become
<xarray.Dataset> Size: 6GB
Dimensions:     (time: 1512, latitude: 721, longitude: 1440)
Coordinates:
    number      int64 8B 1
  * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 12kB 2010-01-01 2010-01-02 ... 2019-12-31
    step        timedelta64[ns] 8B 03:00:00
    surface     float64 8B 0.0
  * latitude    (latitude) float64 6kB 90.0 89.75 89.5 ... -89.5 -89.75 -90.0
  * longitude   (longitude) float64 12kB 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 ... 359.2 359.5 359.8
    valid_time  (time) datetime64[ns] 12kB 2010-01-01T03:00:00 ... 2019-12-31...
Data variables:
    tp          (time, latitude, longitude) float32 6GB dask.array<chunksize=(1, 721, 1440), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes:
    GRIB_edition:            2
    GRIB_centre:             kwbc
    GRIB_centreDescription:  US National Weather Service - NCEP
    GRIB_subCentre:          2
    Conventions:             CF-1.7
    institution:             US National Weather Service - NCEP
    history:                 2024-11-21T16:35 GRIB to CDM+CF via cfgrib-0.9.1...
<xarray.Dataset> Size: 496GB
Dimensions:     (time: 1512, step: 79, latitude: 721, longitude: 1440)
Coordinates:
    number      int64 8B 1
  * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 12kB 2010-01-01 2010-01-02 ... 2019-12-31
  * step        (step) timedelta64[ns] 632B 0 days 06:00:00 ... 10 days 00:00:00
    surface     float64 8B 0.0
  * latitude    (latitude) float64 6kB 90.0 89.75 89.5 ... -89.5 -89.75 -90.0
  * longitude   (longitude) float64 12kB 0.0 0.25 0.5 0.75 ... 359.2 359.5 359.8
    valid_time  (time, step) datetime64[ns] 956kB dask.array<chunksize=(1, 79), meta=np.ndarray>
Data variables:
    tp          (time, step, latitude, longitude) float32 496GB dask.array<chunksize=(1, 79, 721, 1440), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes:
    GRIB_edition:            2
    GRIB_centre:             kwbc
    GRIB_centreDescription:  US National Weather Service - NCEP
    GRIB_subCentre:          2
    Conventions:             CF-1.7
    institution:             US National Weather Service - NCEP
    history:                 2024-11-21T16:36 GRIB to CDM+CF via cfgrib-0.9.1...

The step = 0 days 03:00:00 is seperated from others! How can I correctly read this dataset?
Thanks!
